# HeidiSql connect to older version of mySQL

Tags: mysql, heidisql

I recently installed WAMP server, which apparently upgraded my version of MySQL from 5.7 or something (I don't know). Now, when I open Heidi SQL to access my other databases not related to WAMP, they are no longer there, probably because Heidi is now connecting to a more recent version of MySQL?

I see my old data in C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data.

### How do I reconfigure Heidi to read this folder?

Edited because it wasn't MYSQL 6.0, but Heidi 6.0. I don't know what WAMP did to mySQL to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I had to change the path in my.ini.